# Quantos dia da semana tem no mês?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, data

Olá, boa noite!

Eu pesquisei bastante na internet e não encontrei nada referente a essa dúvida!
Eu gostaria de obter quantos dias da semana existe dentro de um mês usando javascript!
Exemplo:

```
Quantos sábados existe no mês de atual? = 5
Quantas terças-feiras existes no mês atual? = 4
```

Gostaria de um script aonde me informasse a quantidade de dias que existe no més atual.

Agradeço desde já...

Comment: Depende do mês.

Comment: Exatamente! Preciso de um script que me informe a quantidade de dias de acordo com o mes atual.

Comment: Olá chará, Guilherme, sugestão, a maioria dos casos matematica será muito mais eficiente que loop/recursão, então no caso aqui fiz com operação matematica que ficou 90% mais rapido que com loops: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466531/3635, para usos esporádicos é indiferente, mas se for consultar muitas muitos meses pode ser bem vantajoso testar essa proposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz uma [biblioteca para gerar datas](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/js-calendar), numero de semana etc que uso nos meus projetos, pode ser-te útil.

Neste caso é simples e podes fazer em JavaScript. Nota que este script é insensível a feriados :), tens de acrescentar essa lógica à mão.

```js
function getWorkingDays(month) {
  const date = new Date(2020, month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  let workingdays = 0;
  while (month === date.getMonth()) {
    const currentDay = date.getDay();
    const isWeekend = (currentDay === 6) || (currentDay === 0);
    if (!isWeekend) workingdays++; // se não é fds aumentar o nr
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // testar o próximo dia
  }
  return workingdays;
}

// lembra-te que meses têm base 0
// ou seja: janeiro é o mes 0, fevereiro o mes 1, etc...

console.log(getWorkingDays(0));
console.log(getWorkingDays(1));
```

Para saber a quantidade de dias específicos podes fazer uma adaptação do código:

```js
function getDaysByType(month, type) {
  const date = new Date(2020, month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  let count = 0;
  while (month === date.getMonth()) {
    if (date.getDay() === type) count++;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // testar o próximo dia
  }
  return count;
}

// sábado tem o nr 6
// domingo tem o nr 0
// segunda tem o nr 1
// etc

console.log(getDaysByType(0, 0));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 1));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 2));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 3));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 4));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 5));
console.log(getDaysByType(0, 6));
```

Comment: Não é isso que o autor pediu, ele pediu dias especificos, dá pra fazer com loop ou com matematica, pegando o primeiro dia do mes e qual dia da semana ele representa e o ultimo dia do mes e pegar qual dia da semana representa... Então bastaria calcular as semanas e tirar nessas 4 semanas quantos vezes aparece o tipo de dia da semana passado no argumento da função; Por exemplo quantos sábados tem em um mês ou quantas quartas-feiras tem em um mês... Pessoalmente acho q com matematica dá pra ser mais performatico.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de acordar e posso estar lento :P mas na pergunta o AP escreve _"Eu gostaria de obter quantos dias da semana existe dentro de um mês."_ - foi isso que respondi, com um script que gera 1 numero. Não está certo?

Comment: Sim, mas são dias "especificos" e é indiferente se é dia de trabalho ou feriado, ele quer algo assim `contarDiasNoMes('sabado', 'janeiro', 2020); = 4` ou `contarDiasNoMes(6, 1, 2020); = 4`, como ele indicou nos exemplos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou a perceber melhor agora, obrigado! Juntei mais uma variante.

Comment: Fiz uma sugestão, muitas operações dá pra dar uma boa otimizada com matematica https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466531/3635

Answer (score 8):

Usar um while somando dias até resolve o problema:

```
 while (month === date.getMonth()) {
   if (date.getDay() === type) count++;
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // testar o próximo dia
 }
```

Mas o incremento de `date.getDate() + 1` vai gerar incrementos e em média **30 loops**, sendo a maioria desnecessários, se a regra necessitada é um **dia especifico da semana** basta somar **`+7`** dentro do loop ao invés de `+1` e checar se é o mesmo mês depois e então sim fazer a soma `count++`, a função um pouco otimizada pode ficar assim (conforme o teste feito no final da resposta ficou quase 3 vezes mais rápido):

```js
function getDaysByType(type, month, year) {
  const date = new Date(year ? year : new Date().getFullYear(), month, 1, 0, 0, 0);

  var count = 0, increment = 1;

  while (month === date.getMonth()) {
    if (date.getDay() === type) {
        count++;
        increment = 7;
    }

    date.setDate(date.getDate() + increment); // testar o próximo dia
  }
  return count;
}

console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Janeiro:', getDaysByType(0, 0));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Fevereiro:', getDaysByType(0, 1));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Março:', getDaysByType(0, 2));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Abril:', getDaysByType(0, 3));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Maio:', getDaysByType(0, 4));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Junho:', getDaysByType(0, 5));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Julho:', getDaysByType(0, 6));
```

Dessa forma ficará de 4 a 11 loops ao invés de 28 a 31 loops, o que tornou **~70% mais rápido**.

---

No entanto tenho uma outra proposta, usar a **MATEMÁTICA básica**, porque se sabemos que um dia da semana pode aparecer entre 4 e 5 vezes em um mesmo mês com isso temos já como obter por um calculo, precisaremos apenas saber qual o primeiro dia da semana de um mês e qual o ultimo

Dessa forma ficou **~90% mais rápido**:

> Lembrando que 0 = sábado, 1 = domingo, 2 = segunda, 3 = terça, 4 = quarta, 5 = quinta, 6 = sexta
>
> Mês de 0 (Janeiro) a 11 (Dezembro)

```js
function sumWeekDaysInMonth(weekday, month, year)
{
    if (!year) year = new Date().getFullYear();

    // Obtem o ultimo dia do mês
    var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();

    // Obtem primeiro dia da semana do mês
    var firstWeekDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();

    return Math.floor((daysInMonth + (weekday + firstWeekDay) % 7) / 7);
}

console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Janeiro (ano atual):', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 0));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Fevereiro (ano atual):', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 1));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Março (ano atual):', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 2));

console.log('----');

console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Janeiro 1988:', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 0, 1988));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Fevereiro 1988:', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 1, 1988));
console.log('Quantidade de Sábados em Março 1988:', sumWeekDaysInMonth(6, 2, 1988));
```

Para entender melhor, usamos o % para obter o que resta em uma divisão, então:

> dia da semana + primeiro dia da semana do mês / total dias semana (7)
>
> Em janeiro foi (6 + 3) % 7 = 2 (seria como 6+3=9 e 9/7=1,2, arredondando fica 2)
>
> Então soma o numero de dias no mês e divide por 7, 4 foi o resultado que sobrou da divisão:
>
> (31 + 2) / 7 = 4,714285714285714
>
> Depois usa `Math.floor()` para retornar o menor numero inteiro que será "4" para o mês de Janeiro de 2020

Veja o benchmark de todos códigos: https://jsbench.me/lwkdh223r9/1

[image: resultado do benchmark]

- Com while otimizado conseguiu executar quase 3 vezes mais rápido
- Com "matemática" foi o mais rápido realizando quase 10 vezes mais rápido

Comment: Esta pergunta não devia estar fechada , teve duas respostas sinal que foi entendida , fora ser uma pergunta válida na minha modesta opinião.